# How to bring bond0/eth0 interface UP

Tags: linux, network-programming, kernel, linux-device-driver, netfilter

My clusters nodes are mostly tied to eth0 & bond0 interfaces:

```
[root@machine]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:68:79:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:68:79:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 00:25:90:68:79:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
9: brffef350: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: ffef350: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master brffef350 state UP qlen 32
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If I bring down this interface(via: ip link set  down) then connectivity to that node is lost. And then we can't SSH to that node.
Is there a way by which I can restore the connectivity to the nodes? Since the interface went down thus it is prohibiting SSH. Is there a way I can bring these two interfaces UP?

Reason I bring it down because I was contemplating, though not sure, that interface state transition(from up->down->up) might change the interface index(scenario which I wanted to simulate).

Comment: If you want to do up->down->up on a link you rely on for remote management, it can be useful to put both calls into a single command, e.g. `ip link down && ip link up`  Still, very risky if you don't have another way to restore your access.

Answer (score 6):

Using ip:

```
# ip link set dev <interface> up
# ip link set dev <interface> down
```

Using ifconfig:

```
# /sbin/ifconfig <interface> up
# /sbin/ifconfig <interface> down
```

If that does not work try # ifconfig -a

The output from that might help

have you tried pinging?

Answer (score 4):

Bring up all/eth0 the interfaces defined with auto in /etc/network/interfaces :

`ifup -a or ifup eth0`

`ifdown -a or ifdown eth0`

Bring down all interfaces that are currently up:

`ifquery -l`

Print names of all interfaces specified with the allow-hotplug keyword:

`ifquery eth0`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cron job to bring the interface back up. Put a line like this in root's crontab (will work for Debian and derivatives; different command for RedHat, etc):

```
5 10    * * *  /sbin/ifup bond0
```

You just need to change the `5` and `10` in the above to a time a minute or two from when you bring the interface down. In this case, `10` is the hour and `5` is the minute.